# How to get gradle target tasks programmatically?

Tags: gradle

Gradle builds a task graph that depends on which tasks you want to execute.

Depending on the task I want to run (i.e jacocoTestReport, or test), I want to apply a plugin (jacoco).

However, it's not clear how I can get the actual target task(s).

So imagine that I run this cli command:

`$ gradle test`

or

`$ gradle jacocoTestReport`

And in the `build.gradle.kts` file, I have something of the sort:

```kotlin
if("jacocoTestReport" in gradle.targets){
  apply<JacocoPlugin>()
  tasks.named<JacocoReport>("jacocoTestReport") {
        dependsOn("test")
        reports {
            xml.required.set(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Meaning, plugin is only applied if the target is jacocoTestReport.

Why? Because the jacoco java agent makes tests way slower, and I don't need it always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Gradke.getStartParameter](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/invocation/Gradle.html#getStartParameter--) API to query the tasks to be executed, and react accordingly.

Here is a simple example, to apply `jacoco` plugin only if `jacocoTestReport` task has been requested.

```
val taskRequests = gradle.startParameter.taskRequests
if (taskRequests.isNotEmpty() && taskRequests[0].args.contains("jacocoTestReport")) {
    project.apply<JacocoPlugin>()
    // create tasks dependencies
    val jacocoTask = tasks.getByPath("jacocoTestReport")
    tasks.test.configure {
        finalizedBy(jacocoTask)
    }
    jacocoTask.dependsOn(tasks.test)
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this actually modify the taskGraph? kind of confusing. I was expecting to know the target tasks only, not the graph, as I plan to modify it before there's a plan

Comment: @caeus sorry I misunderstood your question and indeed, modifying the task graph after it has been configured might not work , or is not a good idea. I edited the answer to propose another solution based on tasks request, which is I think what you intended to implement.

Comment: that's exactly what I needed, thanks a lot